# ActiveMQ Configuration of default RedeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries for all connections

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am looking for the right way to send all messages to the dead letter queue after a defined amount of retries.

Since the redeliveryPlugin works only with local storage and thus breaks our JDBC based HA configuration, we decided to run all messages into DLQs.

The `individualDeadLetterStrategy` destination configuration comes in handy here:

```
    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
            <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <deadLetterStrategy>
                        <individualDeadLetterStrategy
                                queuePrefix="DLQ."
                                useQueueForQueueMessages="true" />
                    </deadLetterStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" >
                    <deadLetterStrategy>
                        <individualDeadLetterStrategy
                                queuePrefix="DLQ."
                                useQueueForQueueMessages="true" />
                    </deadLetterStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
            </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
```

With this option and setting the maximumRetries in the connection URI (`jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=4`) or in code, I can configure the system quite well.

Yet, I would like to configure the default `redeliveryPolicy` settings for all connections, to enforce a standard over all applications within a broker. Individual application settings may vary, but as I see it currently, I cannot configure the default in the XML - or is there a way?

I tried to do this with redeliveryplugin, but my problem is, that this seems to work only for specific queues, not for all queues. I could not change the default RedeliveryPolicy with the plugin, also I could not remove the delays (minimum 1000):

```
    <plugins>
        <redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true" sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
            <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                    <defaultEntry> 
                        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0" initialRedeliveryDelay="1001" redeliveryDelay="1001" />
                    </defaultEntry> 
                </redeliveryPolicyMap>                  
            </redeliveryPolicyMap>
        </redeliveryPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Why you are saying **that this seems to work only for specific queues** . This config works for all destinations.

Comment: No, in fact, the plugin configuration on the redeliveryPlugin has no effect on the maximumRedeliveries value of the redeliveryPolicy. If I put the `jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries` parameter into the broker URI, I can see a difference. The redelivery plugin configuration has no remarkable effect.

Comment: Do you have the broker's scheduler support enabled? See the last line here: http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Comment: If you have the plugin enabled and no scheduler on, the broker will fail to start. Yes, the scheduler is enabled. But I do not want to use the scheduler, I want to configure the redeliveryPolicy defaults for the browser in the XML

Comment: @HassenBennour regarding "only for specific queues": It works only, if I put the queue name in a policyEntry. Then the redeliveryplugin works for that specific queue. It will not have a global effect on the redeliverypolicy of the broker.

Answer (score 0):

you are right this plugin is not working correctly for topics, due to persistenceAdapter with persistence enabled when resend the message it is considered as a duplicate and discarded. without persistence there is another problem that the message is likely sent and marked as delivered to consumer while not.

you have only the choice to remove the `defaultEntry` and try with adding only one to queues, to send topics undelivedred messages to DLQ.

you have certainly in your logs some things like this `cursor got duplicate send...`  `Duplicate message add attempt rejected. Destination...`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but it missed the point. I wanted to know, if there is a way to globally set the defaults of the RedeliveryPolicy (not the RedeliveryPlugin) of the broker. Currently you can only set the policy in the URI or in code. I do not want to use the redelivery plugin, because it is using the schedulerDB and the schedulerDB stores in a local file (KahaDB) regardless of a configured JDBC or LevelDB persistence. This undermines HA setups, as the slave scheduler is not delivering messages.

Comment: where did you found this information **I do not want to use the redelivery plugin, because it is using the schedulerDB and the schedulerDB stores in a local file (KahaDB) regardless of a configured JDBC or LevelDB persistence.**  RedeliveryPlugin is only doing redelivery and not store messages as i know.

Comment: it is documented on ActiveMQ website and there are issues describing it. You can see it also on the leveldb configuration page. There is no documentation on a secure HA failover with schedulerDB and jdbc storage. see http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html and 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5238